Kafka Topic is not getting created when Debezium PostgreSQL connector are running sucessfully
I am using a debezium connector docker container + Postgres container + Kafka broker docker container.
The connector payload that I am sending is as follows:
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "debezium",
        "database.password": "dbz",
        "database.dbname": "inventory",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "table.include.list": "inventory.customers",
        "topic.prefix": "dbserver1",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
        "topic.creation.enable": "true",
        "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "1",
        "topic.creation.default.partitions": "1"
    }
}

This executes successfully but when I list the Kafka topics only the last 3 topics are present and a new topics are not added.

I created kafka cluster as follows:
version: '3.8'
services:
  # Zookeeper node to manage Kafka cluster
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 2181:2181

  # Kafka broker 1
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19091,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"

  # Kafka broker 2
  kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka2:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"

  # Kafka broker 3
  kafka3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka3
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9094:9094
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka3:19093,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
      

  # Kafka Connect with Debezium
  kafka-connect:
    image: debezium/connect:3.0.0.Final
    container_name: kafka-connect
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
      - zookeeper
      - postgres 
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka1:19091,kafka2:19092,kafka3:19093
      GROUP_ID: "1"
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: debezium_config
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: debezium_offset
      STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: debezium_status
      CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka-connect

  # Kafdrop for monitoring Kafka topics
  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:latest
    container_name: kafdrop
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka1:19091,kafka2:19092,kafka3:19093
    ports:
      - 9000:9000

  # PostgreSQL database for testing CDC
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: debezium
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dbz
      POSTGRES_DB: inventory
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "wal_level=logical"

volumes:
  postgres_data:



Please show connector logs. Also, [mvce] please. You don't need Zookeeper or 3 brokers or a Kafka UI to use debezium container

@OneCricketeer I want to use cluster to be able to scale the system

@OneCricketeer This is the log I got:
https://github.com/1995mars/debezium/blob/main/log.txt

1 broker scales just fine. You're needlessly duplicating data in a single hard drive (making it slower, not more performant) . Please [edit] the post instead.

@OneCricketeer, So I can't use debezium with Kafka cluster, right ?

I never said that. One broker is still considered a Kafka cluster. All of the official debezium tutorials use exactly one broker
